# java: how init a ConcurrentHashMap of integer key and object value

Tags: java

I want a ConcurrentHashMap that have Integer key and Object value ( some value of map are Integer and another is String).
Is this the correct way to init and use my table ?

```
ConcurrentHashMap table=new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable>();
        table.put(new Integer(1), new String("nodata"));
        table.put(new Integer(2), new Integer(23));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points

- You don't need to autobox `int` values and wrapping a String literal is pointless.
- You need to keep the generic type on the left, but using an interface is preferred.
- You would only use Comparable for comparing objects. However, you can't compare objects of different types in general so this is more confusing than useful.

.

```
Map<Integer, Object> table = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
table.put(1, "nodata");
table.put(2, 23);
```

You might want the following if you need the additional methods ConcurrentMap provides.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object> table = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

This appears to be a case of object denial. Using an Object is likely to be a better choice.

```
class MyData {
    private String text;
    private int number;

    MyData(String text, int number) {
        this.text = text;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public synchronized String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public synchronized void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public synchronized int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public synchronized void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

MyData data = new MyData("nodata", 23);
```

---

For a concurrent version of the same.

```
class MyData {
    private final AtomicReference<String> text;
    private final AtomicInteger number;

    MyData(String text, int number) {
        this.text = new AtomicReference<String>(text);
        this.number = new AtomicInteger(number);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text.get();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.set(text);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number.get();
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number.set(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want at least `ConcurrentMap` on the left side, too. It has nice atomic functions that you may need.

Comment: There is something to be said for object denial, but your version synchronizes a lot more than a ConcurrentMap. It is comparable more to a synchronizedMap. Is there a tool to get concurrent beans? Maybe things like AtomicInteger?

Comment: @Thilo Thank you. In this case, I suspect its not neededt ;) but others might find it useful.

Comment: There is a more concurrent version using AtomicReference + AtomicInteger. I can add it for interest but I doubt its really needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it nicely using [initialization blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) and [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm):

```
Map table = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable>() {
  {
    this.put(1, "nodata");
    this.put(2, 23);
  }
};
```

Comment: I discourage initialization blocks. That would create an extra class. Too high a cost for a little syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but don't call all those constructors (String#new is really bad, and the rest can be auto-boxed):

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable> table=
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable>();
    table.put(1, "nodata");
    table.put(2, 23);
```

Coming back to your original question, if you give the reference to `table` to another thread after these three statements, it will see the latest and greatest version of it. Don't share the reference before you called the two puts.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written is correct. Note that you should use

```
    table.put(Integer.valueOf(1), "nodata");
    table.put(Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(23));
```

or even just

```
    table.put(1, "nodata");
    table.put(2, 23);
```

since both `Integer.valueOf` and `new String` have performance better, or at least equal than those of `new Integer` and `new String`.

Comment: i have a warning in consolle Description Resource Path Location Type
ConcurrentHashMap is a raw type. References to generic type ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> should be parameterized ComunicationUtils.java /DashboardDroid/src/it/intects/dashboard/droid/utils line 14 Java Problem
what means ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done will work, but you probably don't need to use all those constructors:

```
table.put(1, "nodata");
table.put(2, 23);
```

To make the code more compact (but perhaps a little harder to understand), you could do this:

```
Map<Integer, Comparable> table=new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable>(){{
    put(1, "nodata");
    put(2, 23);
}};
```

which creates an anonymous subclass of `ConcurrentHashMap` with an initialisation block which calls the `put` method to initialise the map.

Comment: i have a warning in consolle Description Resource Path Location Type ConcurrentHashMap is a raw type. References to generic type ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> should be parameterized ComunicationUtils.java /DashboardDroid/src/it/intects/dashboard/dr‌​oid/utils line 14 Java Problem what means ?

Comment: You should include the type arguments on the left side of the assignment as well: ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable> table = ...

Answer (score 0):

Following Thilo's answer, you can further do this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable> table=
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Comparable>() {{
    put(1, "nodata");
    put(2, 23)
  }}
```

which creates an anonymous class derived from your `HashMap`, and calls it from a static initialiser. It cuts down typing, but be aware that it's a non-obvious creation of an anonymous class. Some people regard this as an abuse of anonymous classes and the above should perhaps be used in limited scenarios (e.g. setting up data for unit tests etc.)

Comment: Java 8 will hopefully, finally give us map literals. Even Objective-C has them now.

Comment: Scala is what you want, of couse :-)